# What do you call an English lover?

Tags: vocabulary, suffixes

Is there a single word for someone who loves the English language? Is it understandable to use *Englishphile*? Has the suffix *-phile* been used correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used the suffix correctly, but I don't believe there is such a word. If so, it is not commonly known and used. An [Anglophile](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Anglophile) is someone who loves England and English things (not America/American), but this term does not specifically refer to the English language, and would not be understood as such without clarification. A [logophile](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/logophile) loves words, but this term does not specify which language and refers only to words, not language in the broad sense. You can just say "I love the English language". Descriptions such as [fanatic](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/fanatic) and its synonyms may also be useful. For example, saying "I'm an English-language fanatic" would do a good job of expressing enthusiasm and eagerness to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is--sort of. The word is *Anglophile*, but it means a love of all things English, not just the English language. Your word would be understood (probably as synonymous with Anglophile), but it isn't the correct word. Nevertheless, you have used the suffix correctly in your invented word.

If you really wanted such a word, perhaps you could invent the word *Anglo-linguaphile* (googling it reveals no examples) and expect that it would be understood (by linguaphiles, at least) as one who loves the English language specfically.

Comment: "**Anglophile**: A person who is fond of or greatly admires England or Britain" Source: [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/anglophile) Thanks for the answer, but that's not exactly the word I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, see my edit. :)